# How do I see the type for operators in F# interactive?

Tags: f#

I am trying to explore the type of operators such as `::` in F# interactive.

But I get these kinds of messages:

```
Unexpected symbol '::' in expression. Expected ')' or other token.
```

even if I surround it with `(::)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
> let inline showmecons a b = a :: b;;

val inline showmecons : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

or

```
> let inline showmepow a b = a ** b;;

val inline showmepow :
   ^a ->  ^b ->  ^a when  ^a : (static member Pow :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^a)
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll see the type of usual operators if you surround them with parentheses:

```
> (+);;
val it : (int -> int -> int) = <fun:it@4-5>
```

Unfortunatelly, this restricts the type of the operator to one specific type - F# Interactive doesn't print the polymorphic definition (with constraints). You can use the workaround suggested by Stephen (and define a new `inline` function) to see that.

The reason why it doesn't work for `::` is that `::` is actually a special syntactic construct (defined directly in the F# specification).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but I'm learning F# and also wanted to figure this out.

Looking at the [F# specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf) on page 32, we see that symbolic keywords also have a compiled name in F#. The equivalent compiled name for `::` is `op_ColonColon`, which actually accepts tuples:

```
> op_ColonColon;;
val it : arg0:'a * arg1:'a list -> 'a list = <fun:clo@22-5>`
```

Using `::` to define an inline function will give us a curried cons function, which is misleading, I believe.